# MySQL condition

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I'm still pretty new with MySQL and I don't know the best way to do this.

I have a table with incremented values, and if the values exceed a certain limit, I'd like to know. So lets say I have this table with a `current` column and `capacity` column. A row in `current` is incremented by user input and I want to know when the value in a `current` row exceeds or meets its corresponding `capacity`.

If `current` is still below the `capacity`, I would like the query to return true. However, if `current` meets or exceeds `capacity`, I would like the query to return false.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `WHERE` clause to do that check in your `UPDATE` query:

```
// I assume you mean you want to increment the current column by 1,
// but it's your table so change the SET values as needed
$updated = mysql_query('UPDATE table SET current = current + 1 WHERE id = ' . intval($row_id) . ' AND current < capacity');
```

Then check `mysql_affected_rows()` of the `UPDATE` query:

```
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
{
    // Success
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I needed. I have one question, though. Whenever I put the variable associated with my `mysql_query` in `mysql_affected_rows`, it wouldn't work (says it wasn't valid MySQL resource). When I removed it and used `mysql_affected_rows()` without an argument, it worked! Do you know why?? Thanks!

Comment: Because it was a mistake on my part: the variable isn't supposed to be there. I've edited my answer to remove it. Sorry for the confusion! Glad my solution worked for you though :)

Answer (score 4):

in mysql that's easy:

```
select (current >= capacity) as exceeded from table
```

Comment: Is => a valid operator in MySQL now, or did you mean >= ?

Comment: Shouldn't this return true only when `current < capacity`?

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I'm actually using UPDATE on the row. How would I apply this to an UPDATE query? Thanks!